# how to fit a curve to a sinusoidal function

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to identify a point reading with a sinusoidal function.
You can see on the image that the result is not satisfactory.
I can't manage to adjust the various parameters of `curve_fit` to fit the function well. What can I do to improve my results?

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit as cf
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

xdata = np.array([0.  , 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1 , 0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18, 0.2 ,
       0.22, 0.24, 0.26, 0.28, 0.3 , 0.32, 0.34, 0.36, 0.38, 0.4 , 0.42,
       0.44, 0.46, 0.48, 0.5 , 0.52, 0.54, 0.56, 0.58, 0.6 , 0.62, 0.64,
       0.66, 0.68, 0.7 , 0.72, 0.74, 0.76, 0.78, 0.8 , 0.82, 0.84, 0.86,
       0.88, 0.9 , 0.92, 0.94, 0.96, 0.98, 1.  , 1.02, 1.04, 1.06, 1.08,
       1.1 , 1.12])
ydata = np.array([37.5, 36.4, 37.1, 37.3, 38.2, 38.4, 38.1, 36.7, 34.3, 32.2, 33.1,
       31.8, 33.4, 35.7, 37.8, 38.3, 38.1, 37. , 34.9, 32.5, 31.6, 31.7,
       33.5, 35.5, 37.8, 38.4, 38.3, 36.9, 34.8, 32.2, 33.9, 31.6, 33.3,
       35.5, 37.6, 38.3, 38.2, 36.7, 34.8, 32.4, 31.5, 32.1, 33.3, 35.5,
       37.2, 38.3, 38.3, 36.8, 34.5, 32.3, 31.6, 31.8, 33.3, 35.7, 37.8,
       38.4, 38.2])


def sin_fun(x,a,b,c,d):
    return a*np.sin(b*x+c)+d

p_opt,p_cov=cf(sin_fun,xdata,ydata )
print(p_opt)
 
plt.plot(xdata,sin_fun(xdata,*p_opt))
plt.plot(xdata,ydata, 'r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In generic terms, the answer from @jared is correct. For sines specifically (or, often, any periodic function), FFT is a more reliable approach, particularly if it's coupled with a second-pass peak interpolation:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

amplitude = np.array((
    37.5, 36.4, 37.1, 37.3, 38.2, 38.4, 38.1, 36.7, 34.3, 32.2, 33.1,
    31.8, 33.4, 35.7, 37.8, 38.3, 38.1, 37. , 34.9, 32.5, 31.6, 31.7,
    33.5, 35.5, 37.8, 38.4, 38.3, 36.9, 34.8, 32.2, 33.9, 31.6, 33.3,
    35.5, 37.6, 38.3, 38.2, 36.7, 34.8, 32.4, 31.5, 32.1, 33.3, 35.5,
    37.2, 38.3, 38.3, 36.8, 34.5, 32.3, 31.6, 31.8, 33.3, 35.7, 37.8,
    38.4, 38.2))

timestep = 0.02
time = np.arange(0, timestep*(len(amplitude) - 0.5), timestep)

# first pass
spectrum = np.fft.rfft(amplitude, norm='forward')
spectral_amplitude = np.abs(spectrum)
freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(n=time.size, d=timestep)
peak_index = 1 + spectral_amplitude[1:].argmax()

# Instead of peak_freq = freqs[peak_index]
# use parabolic peak interpolation from http://www.ericjacobsen.org/fe2/quadterp.txt
a, b, c = spectrum[peak_index-1: peak_index+2]
norm_frac = np.real((a - c)/(2*b - a - c))
peak_freq_interpolated = freqs[peak_index]*(1 + norm_frac) - freqs[peak_index - 1]*norm_frac

# second pass
# shorten the timeseries length so that the peak lands in the next-left bin
excerpt = int(np.round(time.size * freqs[peak_index-1] / peak_freq_interpolated))
spectrum = np.fft.rfft(amplitude[-excerpt:], norm='forward')
spectral_amplitude = np.abs(spectrum)
freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(n=excerpt, d=timestep)
peak_index = 1 + spectral_amplitude[1:].argmax()
peak_freq = freqs[peak_index]
phase_correction = (1 - (len(time) - excerpt)*peak_freq*timestep)*2*np.pi
peak_phase = np.angle(spectrum[peak_index]) + phase_correction
peak_amplitude = 2*spectral_amplitude[peak_index]

print(f'Amplitude: {peak_amplitude:.3f}')
print(f'Frequency (Hz):', peak_freq)
print(f'Phase (deg): {np.rad2deg(peak_phase):.2f}')

reconstructed = peak_amplitude * np.cos(
    2*np.pi*peak_freq*time + peak_phase
) + spectral_amplitude[0]

ax_top: plt.Axes
ax_bottom: plt.Axes
fig, (ax_top, ax_bottom) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

ax_top.plot(time, amplitude, label='experiment')
ax_top.plot(time, reconstructed, label='reconstructed')
ax_top.set_xlabel('Interpolated time (s)')
ax_top.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
ax_top.legend(loc='lower right')

ax_bottom.semilogy(freqs, spectral_amplitude)
ax_bottom.set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ax_bottom.set_ylabel('Amplitude')

plt.show()
```

```
Amplitude: 3.425
Frequency (Hz): 5.0
Phase (deg): 169.70
```

[image: fit]

Comment: très belle solution, mais je ne comprends pas toutes les subtilités de la FFT!
very nice solution, but I don't understand all the intricacies of FFT

Comment: lis e.g. https://www.labunix.uqam.ca/~boukadoum_m/MIC4220/Notes/FFT.pdf

Comment: I have another question, I don't understand how the phase is evaluated.
thanks again

Comment: The primary phase calculation is a simple call to `angle` on a complex value. The correction is necessary because a portion of the time series is cut off for spectral accuracy at the peak.

Answer (score 3):

You can improve your results by giving the function a good initial guess and providing a jacobian function for your objective function.

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

xdata = np.array([0., 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1, 0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18, 0.2,
                  0.22, 0.24, 0.26, 0.28, 0.3, 0.32, 0.34, 0.36, 0.38, 0.4, 0.42,
                  0.44, 0.46, 0.48, 0.5, 0.52, 0.54, 0.56, 0.58, 0.6, 0.62, 0.64,
                  0.66, 0.68, 0.7, 0.72, 0.74, 0.76, 0.78, 0.8, 0.82, 0.84, 0.86,
                  0.88, 0.9, 0.92, 0.94, 0.96, 0.98, 1., 1.02, 1.04, 1.06, 1.08,
                  1.1, 1.12])
ydata = np.array([37.5, 36.4, 37.1, 37.3, 38.2, 38.4, 38.1, 36.7, 34.3, 32.2, 33.1,
                  31.8, 33.4, 35.7, 37.8, 38.3, 38.1, 37., 34.9, 32.5, 31.6, 31.7,
                  33.5, 35.5, 37.8, 38.4, 38.3, 36.9, 34.8, 32.2, 33.9, 31.6, 33.3,
                  35.5, 37.6, 38.3, 38.2, 36.7, 34.8, 32.4, 31.5, 32.1, 33.3, 35.5,
                  37.2, 38.3, 38.3, 36.8, 34.5, 32.3, 31.6, 31.8, 33.3, 35.7, 37.8,
                  38.4, 38.2])


def sin_fun(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a*np.sin(b*x+c)+d


def jac(x, a, b, c, d):
    return np.stack([np.sin(b*x+c),
                     a*x*np.cos(b*x+c),
                     a*np.cos(b*x+c),
                     np.ones_like(x)]).T


guess = [3, 28, -0.5, 35]
p_opt, p_cov = curve_fit(sin_fun, xdata, ydata, jac=jac, p0=guess)
print(p_opt)

x_fine = np.linspace(xdata.min(), xdata.max(), 1000)
y_fine = sin_fun(x_fine, *p_opt)

plt.plot(x_fine, y_fine)
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'x')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Edit: I was asked in the comments about the Jacobian and providing a guess. The Jacobian tells the curve fit function how varying each parameter will affect the results, and it is computed by taking the partial derivative of the objective function with respect to each of the parameters (in order). For the guess, I just eyeballed it based on the plotted data.